# Installing Node on Arduino Yun

Tags: node.js, arduino, arduino-yun, opkg

I have an 8G MicroSD card and I want to install Node for Arduino Yun using opkg but I receive the following message:

```
root@Arduino:~# opkg update
Downloading http://downloads.arduino.cc/openwrtyun/1/packages/Packages.gz.
Updated list of available packages in /var/opkg-lists/attitude_adjustment.
Downloading http://downloads.arduino.cc/openwrtyun/1/packages/Packages.sig.
Signature check passed.
root@Arduino:~# opkg install node
Installing node (v0.10.33-1) to root...
Collected errors:
 * verify_pkg_installable: Only have 2040kb available on filesystem /overlay, pkg node needs 3016
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package node.
root@Arduino:~# df -h
Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
rootfs                    6.9M      4.9M      2.0M  71% /
/dev/root                 7.5M      7.5M         0 100% /rom
tmpfs                    29.8M    480.0K     29.4M   2% /tmp
tmpfs                   512.0K         0    512.0K   0% /dev
/dev/mtdblock3            6.9M      4.9M      2.0M  71% /overlay
overlayfs:/overlay        6.9M      4.9M      2.0M  71% /
/dev/sda1                 7.3G     46.8M      7.2G   1% /mnt/sda1
```

Is there a way to install it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
opkg -d /dev/sda1 install node
```

Seems like the installation is being attempted on `/overlay` which has 6.9MB size

Comment: Have no idea why it is not working :( root@Arduino:~# opkg -d /dev/sda1 install node
Collected errors:
 * resolve_pkg_dest_list: Unknown dest name: `/dev/sda1'.
root@Arduino:~# opkg -d /mnt/sda1 install node
Collected errors:
 * resolve_pkg_dest_list: Unknown dest name: `/mnt/sda1'.

Answer (score 0):

You must first expand your rootfs with 
    'overlay-only -i '

http://www.arduino.org/learning/tutorials/advanced-guides/how-to-enable-the-auto-expanding-of-your-file-system-using-pivot-overlay